# What is "natural bijection" in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

In wikipedia: [Cartesian closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category#:%7E:text=bijection%20between%20the,and%20Z.), there is a description
"a bijection between the hom-sets which is natural in both X and Z." .

Isn't "natural" defined between 2 functors?
What is "morphism is natural in Z"?

I want to know currying through cartesian closure.

Please lecture.

Comment: Natural in really the only way it could by fixing one of the inputs (hom is a bifunctor) and considering projection maps as needed. Nlab has more details: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+closed+category

Answer (score 5):

The mention of

> the existence of a bijection between the hom-sets
> $$\mathrm{Hom}(X\times Y,Z) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(X,Z^Y)$$
> which is natural in both $X$ and $Z$

means (for fixed $Y$): an isomorphism between the functors $C^{\mathrm{op}} \times C \to \mathbf{Set}$ defined by $(X, Z) \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}(X\times Y, Z)$ and $(X, Z) \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}(X, Z^Y)$, respectively.  (Where the actions of these functors on morphisms is left as an exercise for the reader of the Wikipedia page…)